# Displaying the number of occurrences of a letter problem

Tags: c

I have a big problem with my function.

My program (C) is supposed to display the number of occurrences of a letter (Upper or lower case).

The program must handle 2 arguments and work as follows:

```
./rush2 “Just because I don’t care doesn’t mean I don’t understand!” a
4
```

I tried this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rush2(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    int count_letter = 0;

    while (argv[0][i] != '\0') {
        if (argv[0][i] == argv[1][0]) {
            count_letter = count_letter + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("%d", count_letter);
    return (count_letter);
}

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
    rush2(ac, av);
    return (0);
}
```

My function prints 0 or seg faults.
Please help me.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Then as for part of your problem, you should *always* check `argc` before using `argv`. Also you only check the command itself and compare it to the first letter of the first argument (if one exists). That doesn't make much sense. You need to make sure that `argc >= 3` and then compare each character in `argv[1]` to `argv[2][0]`.

Comment: `argv[0]` is not what you think it is. Put `for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) { printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]); }` in the beginning of `rush2` and see.

Comment: `“Just because I don’t care doesn’t mean I don’t understand!”` is suspicious it uses _smart quotes_.  Try `"Just because I don’t care doesn’t mean I don’t understand!"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rush2(char str[], char c_lower)
{
    char c_upper = c_lower - 32;

    int i = 0;
    int count_letter = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] == c_lower || str[i] == c_upper)
        {
            count_letter += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count_letter);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rush2(argv[1], argv[2][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program produces the correct answer. It does not have all the bells-and-whistles like the data checks mentioned in the question comments.